# Java plugin using tomcat/lib

Tags: java, tomcat, reflection

I have a Java webapp which I deploy to Tomcat.

My webapp references a Java project called **MY-API** in which I define some an Interface called **IPlugin**.

I create a new Java project called **MY-PLUGIN** which defines a class called **MyPlugin** which implements **IPlugin**.

I compile **MY-PLUGIN** into a jar file and I put this in **Tomcat/lib**.

I launch my webapp, I have code which scans the classpath and picks up the **MyPlugin** class definition from the jar file that I placed in Tomcat/lib.

I use reflection to create an instace of this class.

```
Object instance = claz.newInstance();
```

I use reflection to ask what interfaces it implements

```
for(Class clazInterface : instance.getClass().getInterfaces()) {
    //check the clazInterface 
}
```

I can see the interface it uses is IPlugin, as I would expect.  Everything seems good so far.

However, if I check the equality of the IPlugin interface with the interface of the same type used by my newly instantiated class, it will tell me the two interfaces are not equal.

```
clazInterface.equals(IPlugin.class)
```

I can see in the debugger the two memory locations are different for each interface class.

What is even more problematic for me is that I am unable to cast my object to IPlugin; I get a class cast exception.

```
IPlugin myPlugin = (IPlugin) instance;
```

I can't work out why I can't cast my object to IPlugin when it defines itself as implementing that interface, grateful for any advice.